# Solution of matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have to solve this matrix equation on **X**:

$$\mathbf {XMX}=\mathbf{zz}^{H}$$

where **X** is diagonal with real elements, **M** is a complex and Toeplitz matrix, **z** is a complex vector.

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestion!

Comment: Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be the diagonal entries of $X$, $M = (m_{ij})$ and $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$. So the matrix equation can be written as $(x_i x_j m_{ij}) = (z_i z_j)$ entrywise. In particular you have $x_k^2 m_{kk} = z_k^2$ and $m_{kk}=m_{k+1,k+1}$since $M$ is Toeplitz.

Comment: The RHS is a rank-1 matrix, while the LHS is full rank.  So either you are looking for a least-squares solution, or else $M$ satisfies further (unspecified) constraints.